# Update Parent Standard Object Getting Sum Value from Child in APEX

Tags: apex, soql, collection

I am new in apex. I want to write a trigger in apex for before insert. I have to standard object (Contact, Opportunity).

```
SELECT sum(amount), Bussiness__c from opportunity where stagename='Closed Won' and id='006i000000Kt683AAB' group by Bussiness__c
```

I want when trigger runs this get sum(Amount) field and Bussiness__c value and then update Contact Total_Business__c with Sum(Amount) Value. Here Bussiness__C is contact id at opportunity object.

Thanks in advance and Waiting for your positive Response.

Comment: Abdul -- Welcome to SFSE.  Marty has a good suggestion below but if you are going to use triggers, I recommend doing an after insert/after update/after delete/after undelete trigger as any of those events could cause changes in your pseudo-rollupsummary field on Contact.  In SFSE, we tend not to write the code for you, but rather want to see you make an effort at writing the trigger and reaching out when you have made a good faith effort and are stuck

Answer (score 0):

Abdul, have you tried implementing [Declarative Rollup Summaries for Lookups](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries)?